# Git command not found, but it's there

Tags: git

Can't launch git command in my Windows 7 console even though the it's added to the system path. I double-checked, it's there, it's git.exe, it should work. Am I forgetting something?

```
Error launching git. The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing same problem in morning. What I did that I uninstalled previous version and installed a new one. I would suggest to uninstall your previous Git version completely. If you re installed this already try to give a reboot your machine and it will work properly.

Comment: Same here on "Git-1.9.4-preview20140815". Uninstalled and installed "Git-1.9.5-preview20150319" and now happy.